# How do I hide a button with data-status = 'Processing' using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is my code after its processed:

```
<button class="btn btn-icon btn-danger command-delete" id="delButton" aria-describedby="tooltip779899" type="button" data-original-title="Delete Sales Order" data-toggle="tooltip" data-target="#modalDelete" data-placement="top" data-row-id="34" data-status="Processed"><span class="zmdi zmdi-delete"></span></button>
```

I need to hide the button when the data-status = "Processed"

Any help is MOST appreciated!

Comment: You could always use .data() to check the data id.  It would be useful to know how the button's data id changes to give you more specific advice though.  https://api.jquery.com/data/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("button[data-status='Processed']").hide();
```

You can select element(s) based on one of it's attribute.

Comment: Thank you thank you thank you!!!!  This solved my issue completely! I didn't know you could select a attribute like that...

Comment: In fact, `$("[data-status='Processed']").hide();` could have been enought too. ;) But it may be good to restrict it to buttons.

Comment: You can see the result here: [Command Buttons](https://www.dropbox.com/s/q0mvok7m8xw7s7k/Capture.PNG?dl=0)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$("button[data-status=\"Processed\"]").hide();
```

BTW, the `$("[attr='value'")` idea can be used to do this with any attribute. For example to select a button with `data-toggle="modal"` you can use:

```
$("button[data-toggle='modal'")
```

Cheers!

Comment: do you mean: $("button[data-status=\"Processed"\"]).hide(); There was no closing bracket